# How to create a new column in the dataframe with the count of equal terms in the other columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
      import pandas as pd
      import numpy as np    

      df_Station = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1024, 1024, 1024, 1024, 1024, 1024,1000, 2000],
                                 'Code_Instrumentation': ['BA182', 'MED1', 'MED1', 'MED1',
                                                          '500-01', '500-01', '500-04', '500-01']})
```

I would like to count the number of items with 'ID' and 'Code_Instrumentation' repeated and add a new column on the dataframe (New_column) with this sum.

I tried to implement the following code. However, it is incorrect:

```
     # Create a list of all IDs
     list_Code_Instrumentation = np.array(df_Station['Code_Instrumentation'])


      df_Station['New_Column'] = 0
      cont = 0

      for i in range(0, len(list_Code_Instrumentation)):    
          aux = list_Code_Instrumentation[i]    

          if(df_Station['Code_Instrumentation'].iloc[i] == aux):


               for j in range(0,len(df_Station)-1):

                  if(df_Station['Code_Instrumentation'].iloc[j] ==
                     df_Station['Code_Instrumentation'].iloc[j+1]):

                       cont += 1

                  df_Station['New_Column'].loc[j] = cont
                  cont = 0
```

This code is resulting in the following (incorrect) output:

```
      ID    Code_Instrumentation    New_Column
     1024          BA182             0
     1024          MED1              1
     1024          MED1              1
     1024          MED1              0
     1024          500-01            1
     1024          500-01            0
     1000          500-04            0
     2000          500-01            0
```

The desired output would be:

```
      ID    Code_Instrumentation    New_Column
     1024          BA182                1 #ID=1024 with Code_Instrumentation=BA182 appeared once
     1024          MED1                 3 #ID=1024 with Code_Instrumentation=MED1 appeared three time
     1024          MED1                 3
     1024          MED1                 3
     1024          500-01               2 #ID=1024 with Code_Instrumentation=500-01 appeared twice
     1024          500-01               2
     1000          500-04               1
     2000          500-01               1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

combine [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) to get the [size](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.size.html) of each grouping

```
df_Station['New_Column'] = df_Station.groupby(["ID","Code_Instrumentation"]).Code_Instrumentation.transform("size")

ID  Code_Instrumentation    New_Column
0   1024    BA182               1
1   1024    MED1                3
2   1024    MED1                3
3   1024    MED1                3
4   1024    500-01              2
5   1024    500-01              2
6   1000    500-04              1
7   2000    500-01              1
```

Answer (score 0):

Grouby and transform:

```
df_Station['New_Column'] = df_Station.groupby(['ID','Code_Instrumentation'])['ID'].transform('count')


ID  Code_Instrumentation    New_Column
0   1024    BA182   1
1   1024    MED1    3
2   1024    MED1    3
3   1024    MED1    3
4   1024    500-01  2
5   1024    500-01  2
6   1000    500-04  1
7   2000    500-01  1
```